# How to convert math formula to c# readable code

Tags: c#, math, formula

Can someone help me to convert this math formula in to C# readable code?

```
m = 11 − (( 7*(a+g) + 6*(b+h) + 5*(c+i) + 4*(d+j) + 3*(e+k) + 2*(f+l) ) mod 11)
```

I tried this way but I think I miss something.

```
int result = (int)new DataTable().Compute(" 11 − (( 7*(a+g) + 6*(b+h) + 5*(c+i) + 4*(d+j) + 3*(e+k) + 2*(f+l) ) mod 11)", null);
```

Comment: do a google search on `DataTable.Compute`

Comment: Duplicating your question with different wording is frowned upon, and unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
var m = 11 − (( 7*(a+g) + 6*(b+h) + 5*(c+i) + 4*(d+j) + 3*(e+k) + 2*(f+l) ) % 11);
```

?

If `a`, `g`, `b`, `h`, `c`, `i`, `d`, `j`, `e`, `k`, `f` and `l` are variables already this should do what you want.